# CMakeLists add_library according to option

Tags: c++, makefile, cmakelists-options

I am trying to build a project (c++ code files) that is to be applied on different type of target machines, and I am trying to include cpp files according to the machine type, for this I created options in the CMakeLists file in order to use them to whether include the cpp file or not.

```
option (MACHINE1 "MACHINE1 DESCRIPTION" OFF)
option (MACHINE2 "MACHINE1 DESCRIPTION" OFF)
...
...
...
add_library (SO_LIBRARY
         SHARED FILE1.cpp
if (MACHINE1)
         FILE2.cpp
endif ()
if (MACHINE2)
         FILE3.cpp
endif ()
         )
...
```

I already have a linked bitbake file where I can set these options on and off, it is not the problem, the issue is that CMakeFile does not accept this type of writing :

```
| CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:52 (add_library):
|   Cannot find source file:
|
|     if
|
|   Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .cu .m .M .mm .h .hh .h++ .hm
|   .hpp .hxx .in .txx
|
|
| CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:52 (add_library):
|   No SOURCES given to target: SO_LIBRARY
```

is there any possible way to do it ?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)

option (MACHINE1 "MACHINE1 DESCRIPTION" OFF)
option (MACHINE2 "MACHINE1 DESCRIPTION" OFF)

add_library(SO_LIBRARY SHARED)

if(MACHINE1)
    target_sources(SO_LIBRARY
      PRIVATE
        FILE2.cpp
    )
endif()
if(MACHINE2)
    target_sources(SO_LIBRARY
      PRIVATE
        FILE3.cpp
    )
endif()
```

In modern CMake (since 3.1) you should [avoid using custom variables in arguments of project commands](https://gist.github.com/mbinna/c61dbb39bca0e4fb7d1f73b0d66a4fd1#avoid-custom-variables-in-the-arguments-of-project-commands) and prefer to use [`target_sources`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_sources.html)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following, Based on the type of the machine, assign the file name to a variable and then use it to add to sources.

```
if(MACHINE1)
set(SOURCEFILES "file1.cpp");
if(MACHINE2)
set(SOURCEFILES "file2.cpp");
if (MACHINE3)
set(SOURCEFILES "file3.cpp");
```

now add the file to add library

```
add_library (SO_LIBRARY
     SHARED ${SOURCEFILES})
```

Comment: Since CMake 3.1 you can use target_sources to append source file to existing target and creating custom variable with list of source files is considered bad practice https://stackoverflow.com/a/73347873/7419651

Answer (score 0):

I would do something along these lines instead of `option`:

```
set(COMMON_SRC File1.cpp)
set(MACHINE1_SRC File2.cpp)
set(MACHINE1_SRC File3.cpp)

if(MACHINE1)
  add_library (SO_LIBRARY SHARED ${COMMON_SRC} ${MACHINE1_SRC_SRC}
elseif(MACHINE2)
  add_library (SO_LIBRARY SHARED ${COMMON_SRC} ${MACHINE2_SRC_SRC}
else()
  ...
endif()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your goal is to create a [list](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/list.html) of sources which content will depend on some conditions.

Start with defining a variable and put there all common source files:

```
set(SOURCES
    file_common_1.cpp
    file_common_2.cpp
)
```

Then, [APPEND](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/list.html#append) elements to `SOURCES` list depending on conditions:

```
if(OPTION1)
    list(APPEND SOURCES file_specific_machine1.cpp)
endif()

if(OPTION2)
    list(APPEND SOURCES file_specific_machine2.cpp)
endif()
```

Finally, use `SOURCES` list to create a library:

```
add_library(SO_LIBRARY ${SOURCES})
```